# How to apply zoom control

Tags: android, android-imageview

How can I apply zoom control in an `ImageView` dynamically? My minimum SDK version is 1.6. I tried most of the samples but in all those an image in the `ImageView` is set on Zoom-in and Zoom-out. I want to Zoom-in and Zoom-out an `ImageView`. I want to increase `ImageView` width and height while Zoom-in and reduce `ImageView` width and height while Zoom-out. Can any one suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes this is the code to increase the size

```
140 is the factor by which image is mulitplied maintaining the height to width ratio
you can change this as you like


  Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(IssueDataHandler.CONTENT_LOCAL_PATH+"/"+coverImageName.trim());
    Bitmap bitmap=originalBitmap;
    if (bitmap !=null) {
        int h = bitmap.getHeight();
        int w = bitmap.getWidth();
        h = 140*h/w;
        w = 140;
        bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, w, h, true);
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```